# Is that Bishop's weed the president is sitting in?

Tags: identification

The Obama's [presidential portraits](https://www.cnn.com/2018/02/12/politics/obama-portrait-unveiling/index.html) were unveiled today.
Did the artist plant Barack in a garden of [Bishop's weed](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=bishops%20weed&t=ffsb&iax=images&ia=images&iai=http%3A%2F%2Ffarm4.static.flickr.com%2F3436%2F4557067674_9d970c7e62_o.jpg)?
Ignoring the flowers, which make little botanical sense, it sure looks like ground elder to me.

Comment: can't be though - bishops weed doesn't grow up walls... its just a stylized version of probably imaginary plants; if it weren't for the flowerheads, could be Boston Ivy

Comment: Sure looks like Bishops Weed to me.  With a bit of license for all the different flowers. Who knows what it was originally, though.  All that artist needed was a branch to get the leaves right and didn't care it didn't grow on walls.  Good job Wayfaring!

Comment: @Bamboo I can't find the line where the ground becomes a wall. I suspect Impressionism is to blame. If I sat on a chair like that in a garden bed like that, at least one leg would sink, and I'd fall over.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger Absolutely - I actually think its a terrible picture, the background just doesn't look right, its ruined a good portrait - for one thing, it looks almost dusty or greyish, a very strange choice

Comment: @Bamboo Some license is allowed at the National Portrait Gallery. Here's a Clinton that's quite striking: https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/01/68/22/2b/bill-clinton.jpg No plants in it though.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger guess its down to personal taste! Clinton looks quite ugly in that pic... but maybe he'd look that way even without the twiddly effects